# How to browse Infinispan cache data in Wildfly 23

Tags: java, console, wildfly, infinispan

I'm having some cache issues in my application (stuff disappearing), and I would like to browse the cache contents in real time to watch what happens to the information stored in there.
Searching on google I've found that Infinispan standalone Server has a console in which you can do that, but I couldn't find any information on how to see the data when using Infinispan as a Wildfly Module. Is there a way to do that?

If not, how would I go about making my application use the Infinispan server instead of the Wildfly module?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the Infinispan Console isn't yet packaged in a way that could be used from within WildFly. In theory you could start an Infinispan Server with the same version used in WildFly and letting it join the cluster as a zero-capacity node. You will then be able to use the console to browse the data in the WildFly caches.